# array reduce is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have a data JSON data which looks like this

```
  [
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 8112.755},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 6198.77},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 8112.755},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 6198.77},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 8112.755},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 6198.77},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 8112.755},
   {gen-acute-sales-before-returns: 6198.77}
  ]
```

basically, I want to sum the total sales value in **gen-acute-sales-before-returns**

I am trying this

```
data.reduce((a, b) => ({totalSales: a.gen-acute-sales-before-returns + b.gen-acute-sales- before-returns})))
```

It is giving error

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: acute is not defined

Comment: You can't access JavaScript variable names with dashes with dot notatation. You need to use bracket notation. So `a["gen-acute-sales-before-returns"]` and not `a.gen-acute-sales-before-returns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because for the **JSON** keyValue, you are not able to use the **-**.
So with below code it will work.

```
let values = [
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 8112.755},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 6198.77},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 8112.755},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 6198.77},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 8112.755},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 6198.77},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 8112.755},
   {"gen-acute-sales-before-returns": 6198.77}
 ]

values.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue["gen-acute-sales-before-returns"]
    ,0
);


// 57246.09999999999
```

Comment: btw, i see no [JSON](http://json.org/).